# Find Group Action

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I'm asked to find a group action G on the unit cylinder C such that $C/G$ is homeomorphic to the torus.  Would $\pm1 \cdot (x,y,z) = (x,y,\pm z)$ work?  The only problem here is that G should only act on the boundary circles, but implementing that restriction makes G not an action on C.

Comment: The unit cylinder is $\{(x,y,z) : x^2+y^2 = 1\}$? Anyway, topologically, it is $S^1\times \mathbb{R}$. You want $S^1\times S^1$, so how do you get a group action on $\mathbb{R}$ such that the orbit space is a circle?

Comment: No, $|z| \le 1$.  $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1$ with the action $n \cdot x = n + x$, but this won't work for $[-1,1]$.  Also, we haven't learned about these direct products yet.

Comment: With $S^1\times [-1,1]$, it's not as easy. I think you need a twist then.

Comment: How exactly do you mean?  A twisted cylinder in the standard sense is not homeomorphic to the torus

Comment: I'm not sure whether it works. But if you just flip the cylinder to identify the two boundary curves, you have a fixed circle in between that becomes a boundary circle - $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,y,-z)$ just produces a cylinder homeomorphic to the one you started with. If you twist the cylinder when swapping the two boundary curves, it might work. If the interval were open, it would be easy, just a translation, but with the boundaries, I don't know.

Comment: Pretty sure a flip won't work regardless of any rotation you do - the orientation switches , so a right hand travelling once around the "torus" result ends up as a left hand.